# Is there a way to run regular jUnit tests with my Cucumber test runner?

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, junit, cucumber

I have a Java project set up with Maven, which I am testing with both Cucumber and jUnit.

Maybe I am missing something, but is there a way to set up my Cucumber test runner to automatically run jUnit tests along with my cucumber features? It would be great not to have to run two separate test suites, and to automatically test everything with `mvn test`.

At the moment, when I specify `@RunWith(Cucumber.class)`, it just looks for `.feature` files and ignores all other tests.

Here is my test file structure:

```html
    └── test
        ├── java
        │   ├── TestRunner.java
        │   └── com
        │       └── myname
        │           └── server
        │               ├── GlobalHooks.java
        │               ├── HTTPRequestsSteps.java
        │               └── unitTests
        │                   ├── RequestHandlerTests.java
        │                   └── ServerTests.java
        └── resources
            └── cucumber
                ├── ... cucumber features here
```

And my test runner, which currently just looks for `.feature` files.

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin={"pretty"}, glue="com.rnelson.server", features="src/test/resources")

public class TestRunner {
}
```

I have been searching to no avail, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your `unitTests` do not follow the maven SureFire [naming conventions](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html) (they end in `Tests` rather than `Test`). Could that be the reason they are not discovered and thus not run by `mvn test`?

Comment: Perfect, this solved my problem. Thanks!!

Comment: @BeccaNelson did you get this working ? Even I've similar situation but I'm not sure how to solve it ? Below answer didn't help me

Comment: My problem was just a naming problem, as @avandeursen pointed out above.

Answer (score 2):

What about this Becca:

From cucumber offical docs:

> JUnit Runner
>
> The JUnit runner uses the JUnit framework to run Cucumber. All you
>   need is a single empty class with an annotation:

```
package mypackage;

import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class RunCukesTest {
}
```

> You can run this test in the same way you run your other JUnit tests,
>   using your IDE or your build tool (for example mvn test).

Also this could be useful to you:

http://www.hascode.com/2014/12/bdd-testing-with-cucumber-java-and-junit/

Here i'm doing exactly the same thing, cucumber run Junit and will produce both result, xml Junit reports and html Cucumber report with just one click on our Jenkins job...

If you mean that you want to run also the test as JUnit test, you cannot combine Junit annotations with Cucumber annotations. but you can easily separate both the classes, and then run both with "mvn test" goal..

Last thing, i consider this the last solution but it should work, you can also call the Junit test directly from code, but it will be a really dirty and no standard solution...

```
JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
Result result = junit.run(testClasses);
```

Is it clear? :) Or maybe you needs are different?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a misunderstanding to me.

JUnit tests are written using JUnit and will reside in java classes. They will be executed by Maven if the name is properly formatted so it gets picked up by the Maven test runner.

One JUnit class is annotated with `@RunWith(Cucumber.class)`. It is a JUnit class that runs Cucumber. This is just another Java class, but this class searches for `.feature` files and tries to execute those it finds. It is also special in that it will not allow you to have any methods defined in it. Except from this, it is a regular JUnit class that will be executed at the same time as any other JUnit classes.

So, all test classes will be picked up and executed. One of them will try to run your Cucumber scenarios.

There is nothing contradicting that you have many test classes in the same project. Even in the same package.